# LAMP : PHP not executed, downloded instead

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I bought a server online and installed LAMP on in (with 1-click, I didn't configure anything).

I now need to create a dynamic page using php, but if a create a file `test.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello!";
?>
```

When I connect to `http://serverIP/test.php` instead of showing me an empty page which says `Hello!` it keeps downloading `test.php` on my computer as a file!

Please note:

1. `test.php` is in `/var/www/html` next to `index.html` and many others .html files that work correctly.
2. If I type `php -v` in the command-line it says that

   php 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed.
3. When I type `a2enmod php7.0` it says

   Module php7.0 already enabled
4. With LAMP i got installed `Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache 2.4.18` (Ubuntu).
5. can't see a folder named "modules" in `/etc/apache2`
6. When I modify any file I also restart apache (`service apache2 restart`)

This is how my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` looks like (without all the comments):

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf


#the following lines are what I added
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so ### in "etc/apache2" there isn't a folder named "modules" ###
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: did you install libapache2-mod-php7.0 `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0`

Comment: Yes, I found it installed by default (just like php7.0)

Comment: Yes, php7.0 is enabled (as I wrote). Removing those lines doesn't solve the problem, I just tried...

Comment: I added it in the post. I check from both Chrome and FireFox Focus  (which shouldn't save any data) from my smartphone (I also deleted the cache: still doesn't work)

Comment: `/var/www/html`(owner: www-data www-data, permission: drwxrwxr-x). `/var/www/html/test.php`(owner: root root, permission: -rwxr-xr-x).

Comment: Actually I never touched anything about nginx

Comment: can you post the output of `sudo lsof -i :80` and `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

Comment: here it is @Panther : http://tinypic.com/r/2b18j6/9

Comment: Well there you go, you are not running Apache =) You can either stop nginx and start apache or we can configure nginx, your choice. `sudo service stop nginx && sudo start apache2`

Comment: NOW IT WORKS! Oh my God, you are the best @Panther ! Thanks a lot! You can't imagine how happy I am right now!! You really saved! Thanks, thanks, Thaks a lot!

Comment: I saw the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/974433/566421), but this do nothing: `<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Panther](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/panther) it turned out I was using nginx, not apache... so problem solved. Thanks again [@Panther](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/panther)!

You probably want to remove or disable nginx

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/php/7.0/` to make sure you have `php7.0-cgi` installed. You should have an `apache2` folder in there, if all you see is a `cli` folder you will need to `sudo apt-get install php7.0-cgi`, then restart Apache.

Comment: In my apache2 folder I have 3 folders: `cli`, `apache2` and `mods-available`. I did `apt-get install php7.0-cgi` (and it wasn't installed!), restarted Apache, but I still see those 3 folders, and it still downloads test.php on my computer

Comment: EDIT: a folder named "cgi" appeared, but it keeps downloading `test.php` instead of displaying it ( I also did `a2enmod cgi` and restarted Apache...)

Comment: @MauroFari did you nuke your browser cache?  Browsers are notorious for 'caching' how to handle things.

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache a couple times. I also try from my smartphone using FireFox Focus, which doesn't save any data (cache included)

Comment: Can you cut and paste the lists that you get when you type `a2enmod` and `a2dismod`.  Nothing after the commands will give you a list for both enabled and disabled modules. `Ctrl+C` to exit out of the module entry prompt. Also have you edited any `.htaccess` files or have you entered any specific rewrite variables into the `apache2.conf` file? NVM: See your NGINX update now.